# Why different behaviour of trapping EXIT vs INT

Tags: bash, signals, trap

Running `bash` 4.3 on Kubuntu Trusty 64 bit. Please see the following two files:

trapping-int.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
trap "echo Exiting" INT
cat </dev/urandom >/dev/null
echo Hello
```

trapping-exit.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
trap "echo Exiting" EXIT
cat </dev/urandom >/dev/null
echo Hello
```

Now upon hitting ^C, trapping SIGINT prints both `Exiting` and `Hello` whereas trapping EXIT prints `Exiting` only but with an extra newline:

```
$ ./trapping-int 
^CExiting
Hello
$ ./trapping-exit 
^CExiting

$
```

I would like to know the reason for the differing behaviour. Also, can I safely assume that EXIT is always called even if INT is given by ^C?

Commenting out the last line in both scripts causes trapping SIGINT to no longer print the Hello but trapping EXIT still prints the extra newline. I'd like to know the reason here too.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, I see this same behavior on Arch linux, 64 bit, bash 4.3.30(1)-release

Answer (score 11):

First, a summary of some facts about signals and the shell:

- When you press CTRL+C at the keyboard, a SIGINT is sent to all processes in the process group of the foreground process.  In this case, it means a SIGINT will be received by both the `cat` command and the `bash` process interpreting your script.
- When you trap `INT`, an `INT` will no longer cause the process to exit unless you explicitly exit in your handler.
- When you trap `EXIT`, your argument is run not on a particular signal but rather on the exit from the shell.

The behavior of  `trapping-int.sh` is straightforward given these facts, since we know the following happens:

- The `cat` process receives a SIGINT and its execution is terminated.
- The `bash` process receives a SIGINT and runs its signal handler, printing "Exiting\n" to `STDOUT`.
- The `bash` process continues execution, and prints "Hello\n" to `STDOUT`.
- The `bash` process exits when it reaches the end of the script.

The behavior of `trapping-exit.sh` is mostly straightforward as well:

- The `cat` process receives a SIGINT and its execution is terminated.
- The `bash` process receives a SIGINT and since there is no signal handler it also, exits.  It does /not/ run the `echo` command since it is exiting immediately upon receiving the signal.
- Since the `bash` process is exiting, the `EXIT` handler runs, printing "Exiting\n" to `STDOUT`.

The remaining question is "where is the newline coming from?" I believe what is happening is that bash itself is installing a `SIGINT` handler that prints a newline.

In your `trapping-int.sh` script, you override Bash's handler for `SIGINT`, so you don't get the extra newline.